# How can I convert a ConcurrentDictionary to a Dictionary?

Tags: c#, .net, dictionary, concurrentdictionary

I have a ConcurrentDictionary object that I would like to set to a Dictionary object.

Casting between them is not allowed. So how do I do it?

Answer (score 51, accepted):

The [`ConcurrentDictionary<K,V>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd287191.aspx) class implements the [`IDictionary<K,V>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/s4ys34ea.aspx) interface, which should be enough for most requirements. But if you really need a concrete [`Dictionary<K,V>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xfhwa508.aspx)...

```
var newDictionary = yourConcurrentDictionary.ToDictionary(kvp => kvp.Key,
                                                          kvp => kvp.Value,
                                                          yourConcurrentDictionary.Comparer);

// or...
// substitute your actual key and value types in place of TKey and TValue
var newDictionary = new Dictionary<TKey, TValue>(yourConcurrentDictionary, yourConcurrentDictionary.Comparer);
```

Comment: Note that the dictionary to copy might use a non-default `IEqualityComparer` that won't be preserved that way!  
Better: `var newDict =
dict.ToDictionary(kvp => kvp.Key, kvp => kvp.Value, dict.Comparer);`

Comment: Note that [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.concurrent(v=vs.110).aspx) says this may not be thread safe.  How would you make it thread safe?

Comment: Don't worry, it actually is thread-safe, by virtue of the ConcurrentDictionary. You will get a snapshot of the ConcurrentDictionary's content. The dictionary you get from that won't be thread-safe itself later on though.

Comment: @Falanwe: It is safe, but you don't get a snapshot of the contents: _"The enumerator returned from the dictionary is safe to use concurrently with reads and writes to the dictionary, however it does not represent a moment-in-time snapshot of the dictionary. The contents exposed through the enumerator may contain modifications made to the dictionary after GetEnumerator was called."_ (From the _Remarks_ section of https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd287131.aspx)

Answer (score 23):

Why do you need to convert it to a Dictionary? `ConcurrentDictionary<K, V>` implements the `IDictionary<K, V>` interface, is that not enough?

If you really need a `Dictionary<K, V>`, you can *copy* it using LINQ:

```
var myDictionary = myConcurrentDictionary.ToDictionary(entry => entry.Key,
                                                       entry => entry.Value);
```

Note that this makes a *copy*. You *cannot* just assign a ConcurrentDictionary to a Dictionary, since ConcurrentDictionary is not a subtype of Dictionary. That's the whole point of interfaces like IDictionary: You can abstract away the desired interface ("some kind of dictionary") from the concrete implementation (concurrent/non-concurrent hashmap).

Answer (score 14):

I think i have found a way to do it.

```
ConcurrentDictionary<int, int> concDict= new ConcurrentDictionary<int, int>( );
Dictionary dict= new Dictionary<int, int>( concDict);
```

Answer (score 2):

```
ConcurrentDictionary<int, string> cd = new ConcurrentDictionary<int, string>();
Dictionary<int,string> d = cd.ToDictionary(pair => pair.Key, pair => pair.Value);
```

Answer (score 1):

If you only need to guarantee thread-safety, but not a moment-in-time snapshot, use `concurrentDictionary.ToDictionary(kvp => kvp.Key, kvp => kvp.Value);`.

This is because `.ToDictionary()` is simply the LINQ implementation that operates over IEnumerable. The `ConcurrentDictionary` enumerator is thread-safe, but the values can change underneath you as the enumerator is enumerated.

If you need to guarantee a moment-in-time snapshot, use `concurrentDictionary.ToArray().ToDictionary(kvp => kvp.Key, kvp => kvp.Value);`.

`.ToArray()` is implemented by the `ConcurrentDictionary` itself, and uses an internal lock to guarantee a moment-in-time snapshot of the dictionary contents. You may then do whatever you like with the resultant array, such as creating a new dictionary from its values.

Answer (score 1):

Converting a `ConcurrentDictionary<K,V>` to a `Dictionary<K,V>` has a couple of gotchas.

1. The two dictionaries should have the same [`Comparer`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.dictionary-2.comparer). Otherwise two keys
   that are different according to the one comparer might be equal according to the other comparer, in which case attempting to insert the second key in the target dictionary will cause a run-time `ArgumentException` with the message *"An item with the same key has already been added."*
2. Although in practice a `ConcurrentDictionary<K,V>` [emits unique keys](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65417001/is-it-safe-to-copy-a-concurrentdictionary-to-a-normal-dictionary-by-enumerating) when it is enumerated, this is not guaranteed by [the documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.concurrent.concurrentdictionary-2.getenumerator#remarks), and the Microsoft engineers have explicitly stated that the observed behavior [is not intentional](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/issues/46374#issuecomment-754123250). So there is nothing that prevents them from changing the current implementation in a future .NET version, in a way that will allow the emission of duplicate keys during a single enumeration of a `ConcurrentDictionary<K,V>` instance. This could cause again the appearance of run-time `ArgumentException`s, if you use the `Dictionary<K,V>` constructor that has a `collection` or `dictionary` parameter. If you want to be on the safe side, it's a good idea to be defensive, and insert the key-value pairs in the `Dictionary<K,V>` with either the [`TryAdd`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.dictionary-2.tryadd) method or the `set` [indexer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.dictionary-2.item). The `TryAdd` will preserve the first occurrence of the duplicate key, while the `set` indexer will preserve the last.

```
/// <summary>
/// Creates a Dictionary from a ConcurrentDictionary.
/// </summary>
public static Dictionary<TKey, TValue> ToDictionary<TKey, TValue>(
    this ConcurrentDictionary<TKey, TValue> source, bool snapshot = false)
{
    ArgumentNullException.ThrowIfNull(source);
    if (snapshot)
        return new Dictionary<TKey, TValue>(source.ToArray(), source.Comparer);

    // Create a Dictionary without snapshot semantics.
    Dictionary<TKey, TValue> result = new(source.Comparer);
    foreach (var (key, value) in source)
        result.TryAdd(key, value); // or result[key] = value;
    return result;
}
```