# How do you convert a dictionary to a ConcurrentDictionary?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, dictionary, concurrentdictionary

I have seen how to convert a [ConcurrentDictionary to a Dictionary](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4330702/how-can-i-convert-a-concurrentdictionary-to-a-dictionary), but I have a dictionary and would like to convert to a ConcurrentDictionary.  How do I do that?... better yet, can i set the link statement to be a ConcurrentDictionary?

```
var customers = _customerRepo.Query().Select().ToDictionary(x => x.id, x => x);
```

Comment: What LINQ provider are you using? Is the result of `Query()` or `Select()` an IQueryable or an IEnumerable?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Use 
[`ConcurrentDictionary<TKey, TValue> Constructor (IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<TKey, TValue>>)` constructor](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd287236(v=vs.110).aspx) which can accept a dictionary object like:

```
Dictionary<int, string> dictionary = new Dictionary<int, string>();
dictionary.Add(1,"A");
dictionary.Add(2, "B");

ConcurrentDictionary<int,string> concurrentDictionary = 
             new ConcurrentDictionary<int, string>(dictionary);
```

> can i set the *LINQ* statement to be a ConcurrentDictionary?

No. <strike>You can not.</strike>. There is no extension method available to create `ConcurrentDictionary`  in LINQ. You can either create your own extension method or you can use the `ConcurrentDictionary` constructor in your LINQ  query while projecting results.

Comment: Well you could project the results to a dictionary using LINQ, but you would have to write your own `ToConcurrentDictionary` extension method to do it. (You might be able to get rid of the intermediate dictionary and insert directly using a `foreach` and taking in a key and value selector delegate).

Comment: You *can* use LINQ, with the constructor you mentioned. Create a KeyValuePair from the original enumerable with the desired key and values, then pass it to the constructor, eg. `myEnumerable= ... Select(item=>new KeyValuePair(item.Id,item); ... new ConcurrentDictionary(myEnumerable);`. No need for a ForEach, although an extension method would make the code slightly cleaner

Answer (score 7):

Why not write your own extension method:

```
  public static class ConcurrentDictionaryExtensions {
    public static ConcurrentDictionary<TKey, TElement> ToConcurrentDictionary<TSource, TKey, TElement>(this IEnumerable<TSource> source, Func<TSource, TKey> keySelector, Func<TSource, TElement> elementSelector, IEqualityComparer<TKey> comparer) {
        if (source == null) throw new ArgumentNullException("source");
        if (keySelector == null) throw new ArgumentNullException("keySelector");
        if (elementSelector == null) throw new ArgumentNullException("elementSelector");

        ConcurrentDictionary<TKey, TElement> d = new ConcurrentDictionary<TKey, TElement>(comparer ?? EqualityComparer<TKey>.Default);
        foreach (TSource element in source)
            d.TryAdd(keySelector(element), elementSelector(element));

        return d;
    }

    public static ConcurrentDictionary<TKey, TSource> ToConcurrentDictionary<TSource, TKey>(this IEnumerable<TSource> source, Func<TSource, TKey> keySelector) {
        return ToConcurrentDictionary<TSource, TKey, TSource>(source, keySelector, IdentityFunction<TSource>.Instance, null);
    }

    public static ConcurrentDictionary<TKey, TSource> ToConcurrentDictionary<TSource, TKey>(this IEnumerable<TSource> source, Func<TSource, TKey> keySelector, IEqualityComparer<TKey> comparer) {
        return ToConcurrentDictionary<TSource, TKey, TSource>(source, keySelector, IdentityFunction<TSource>.Instance, comparer);
    }

    public static ConcurrentDictionary<TKey, TElement> ToConcurrentDictionary<TSource, TKey, TElement>(this IEnumerable<TSource> source, Func<TSource, TKey> keySelector, Func<TSource, TElement> elementSelector) {
        return ToConcurrentDictionary<TSource, TKey, TElement>(source, keySelector, elementSelector, null);
    }

    internal class IdentityFunction<TElement> {
        public static Func<TElement, TElement> Instance
        {
            get { return x => x; }
        }
    }

}
```

*Simply adopted the code from the [.Net framework](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Core/System/Linq/Enumerable.cs,a6091311eadfdd8a).*

Comment: Not sure why but unless you pass a comparer this will throw. See [source](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/Collections/Concurrent/ConcurrentDictionary.cs,332)

Comment: @MotKohn: You're right. Fixed the code according to the [source](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/Collections/Concurrent/ConcurrentDictionary.cs,177)

Answer (score 4):

A LINQ-To-Objects statement is ultimately an IEnumerable so you can pass it to the ConcurrentDictionary constructor, eg:

```
var customers = myCustomers.Select(x => new KeyValuePair(x.id, x));
var dictionary=new ConcurrentDictionary(customers);
```

This may not work with other providers. Linq to Entities for example, converts the entire LINQ statement to SQL and can't projection to a KeyValuePair. In this case you may have to call `AsEnumerable()` or any other method that forces the IQueryable to execute, eg:

```
var customers = _customerRepo.Customers.Where(...)
                             .AsEnumerable()
                             .Select(x => new KeyValuePair(x.id, x));
var dictionary=new ConcurrentDictionary(customers);
```

`Select()` with no arguments is not an IEnumerable or IQueryable method so I suppose it's a method provided by some other ORM. If `Select()` returns an IEnumerable you can use the first option, otherwise you can use `AsEnumerable()`

Comment: Note that you can do `AsEnumerable()` [on a enumerable](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb335435(v=vs.100).aspx) and it will not hurt anything.

Answer (score 0):

Or just a have method:

```
 private ConcurrentDictionary<TKey, TValue> ToConcurrent<TKey, TValue>(Dictionary<TKey, TValue> dic) {
        return new ConcurrentDictionary<TKey, TValue>(dic);
    }
```

and then do:

```
var customers = _customerRepo.Query().Select().ToDictionary(x => x.id, x => x);
var concurrentDic = ToConcurrent(customers);
```

Personally, I'm going with the extension method that I just updated...